# JSON PHP Key with same name

Tags: php, arrays, json

Chatfuel gives this as a way to respond back:

```
{
"messages": [
{"text": "Welcome to the Chatfuel Rockets!"},
{"text": "What are you up to?"}
]
}
```

I want to output something like this with My text, but keys with same value are not possible, since it outputs the first key with the last value

```
<?php
 $arr = array(array('messages' => array('text' => "Text 1", 'text' => "text 
 2")));


 if ("test" == "test"){
  echo json_encode($arr);
 }
```

Output: [{"messages":{"text":"text 2"}}]

How do I output a way like requested by chatfuel?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make this fairly verbose so you can see how the structure is being generated. There is an outer object that contains a "messages" property which is an array of "message" objects each with a "text" property.

V1

```
$json = new stdClass();
$json->messages = array();

$message = new stdClass();
$message->text = 'Welcome to the Chatfuel Rockets!';
$json->messages[] = $message;

$message = new stdClass();
$message->text = 'What are you up to?';
$json->messages[] = $message;

echo json_encode( $json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
```

---

V2

```
$json = array(
  'messages' => array(
    array(
      'text' => 'Welcome to the Chatfuel Rockets!'
    ),
    array(
      'text' => 'What are you up to?'
    ),
  )
);

echo json_encode( $json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = ['messages' => [['text' => 'Text 1'], ['text' => 'Text 2']]];
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "text": "Text 1"
        },
        {
            "text": "Text 2"
        }
    ]
}
```